# Date format filter is not working angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am new to angular js .
I am trying to give some date format like `Nov-24-2016`, but its not working at all .
Below is my code.

```html
{{ x.created | date:" MM-d-y" }}
```

Here  I want this format  `Nov-24-2016`

and `x.created value  = 2016-11-24 08:02:21`

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a custom

```
.filter('datetime', function($filter){
    return function(input){
      if(input == null){ return ""; } 

      var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input),'MM-dd-yyyy');         
      return _date.toUpperCase();

    };
});


{{ x.created | datetime }}
```

Comment: Hi i am getting like this   NOVEMBER-24-2016
I want it to be short end the month name to NOV

I have used this format

 var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'MMMM-dd-yyyy');

Comment: try using 'MMM' in months

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

x.created must be either a Date object or a timestring with milliseconds since UTC epoch.

So either create a manual filter for it or parse your datestring to a Date object.

Answer (score 1):

To use `date` Pipe `x.created` must be date object or a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch) or an ISO string as per [DatePipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)

Answer (score 0):

`{{ x.created | date: "MMM-d-y" }}` renders to `Nov-24-2016`

Btw: `2016-11-24 08:02:21` seems not to be a valid ISO string, https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime. You could check this.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. It's fix after 2 steps, change document encoding to utf-8 without BOM and rewrite manually data of time. Like this - date: 
`2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z`